# How can I view scheduled tasks in a calendar view?

Tags: windows, calendar, scheduled-tasks

I have a number of tasks rigged up using Windows' Task Scheduler.  These are all recurring tasks, and I expect there to be more of them in the future.  What I want is to be able to view all scheduled tasks in a calendar view so as my task library grows I do not inadvertently schedule overlapping items that may slow down or crash my computer.

Is there a way to integrate my scheduled tasks into a calendar view, in this way?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

SQL Sentry has a paid tool called "Power Suite for Windows" that lets you view Task Scheduler tasks in calendar view - http://www.sqlsentry.com/Suites/PowerSuiteWindows. You can get a 1 month trial with it if you fill out a survey.

Having just downloaded it and played with it for a few minutes, by default it shows all tasks (custom ones you created as well as all the standard tasks that ship with windows) so you'll need to group the tasks together by something to "filter" them so your calendar is not so jam packed. I highlighted some areas in the toolbar that help break things down. [image: What the calendar view looks like grouped by owner]